# HP stream with 32Gb HDD

Tags: windows-10-v1511

How the hell do I upgrade Win10 to latest version when the current win10 takes up 20Gb and the upgrade is requesting 20Gb. I have moved what I can to a SSD card and currently have 3Gb left, but why is Microsoft requesting another 20Gb to perform an upgrade.

Comment: Because the upgrade works.  Windows is installed over the current location, and your files and applications are moved to another portion, have you tried using a flash drive and starting the setup from that location?

Comment: have you tried the steps from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

An Microsoft employee explained it [here in a video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Lots-of-Windows-10-Stick-PCs-PST-tips-Zombie-Libraries-and-more#time=2m00s). You need to attach a USB hub and insert 2 16GB USB thumb drives. On 1 drive you put the extracted ISO and the 2nd one must be empty and during running setup.exe from the 1st USB drive, it shows you that you need more space:

[image]

Select here the 2nd empty drive as temporary drive (`Choose another drive or attached external drive`).